# How to create a day trend scatter plot by multiple variables

Tags: r, plot, stata

I am trying to create a scatter plot by following several variables. I am wondering how can I show the day trends by following the state. Please let me know anything needs to provide. Thank you very much!
The data are shown below.

```
State Day1 Day2 Day3 Day4
CA    1    5     7    9
NY    10   8    20    90 
VT    4   6    9    10
```

Answer (score 0):

### Base R

Use `matplot` to get all the lines at once. But the data must be transposed, R uses column first order.

```
matplot(t(df1[-1]), type = "l", lty = 1)
legend("topleft", legend = df1$State, col = 1:3, lty = 1)
```

[image]

---

### Package `ggplot2`

With package `ggplot2`, this type of problems generally has to do with reshaping the data. The format should be the long format and the data is in wide format. See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2185252/reshaping-data-frame-from-wide-to-long-format) on how to reshape the data from wide to long format.

```
library(ggplot2)

df1 |>
  tidyr::pivot_longer(-State, names_to = "Day") |>
  dplyr::mutate(Day = as.integer(sub("[^[:digit:]]+", "", Day))) |>
  ggplot(aes(Day, value, color = State)) +
  geom_line()
```

[image]

---

### Data

```
df1 <- read.table(text = "
State Day1 Day2 Day3 Day4
CA    1    5     7    9
NY    10   8    20    90 
VT    4   6    9    10 
", header = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 0):

In Stata you need a `long` layout for this to work well -- just as in `ggplot2` in R. After something like

```
clear 
input str2 State Day1 Day2 Day3 Day4
CA    1    5     7    9
NY    10   8    20    90 
VT    4   6    9    10 
end 

reshape long Day, i(State) j(Time)
rename Day Whatever 
encode State, gen(Where)
xtset Where Time
```

you can check out `tsline` and `xtline`. But: if your real data are 50 states of the United States (plus DC? Puerto Rico? Guam? ??) then your data define 50?+ lines and some strategy may be needed.